# C# Using SimpleTCPIP from NeGet with VS 2019 Compilation Error System.Net.IPAddrerss.Parse()

Tags: c#

This is a clip from the sample SimpleTCP Server. The VS 2019 compiles with an error on the line:

System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);

How do I fix it?

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtStatus.Text += "Service starting ...";
        System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);     
        server.Start(ip).Convert.toInt32(txtPort.Text);
    }
```

Produces:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.IPAddress' to 'int' WindowsFormsApp1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Start function signature of the server is

```
SimpleTcpServer Start(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
```

I think what you want is:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtStatus.Text += "Service starting ...";
    System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);
    int port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text);     
    server.Start(ip, port);
}
```